# How to set image as wallpaper using Android Phonegap?

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm using `Phonegap` and `Jquery Mobile` on an Android app. I need to save an image from URL and set it as a wallpaper.

I found the Phonegap [Downloader](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/Downloader) plugin that can handle the downloading part. Is there a plugin that implemanets "set as wallpaper" functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create Phonegap Plugin
package com.android.test;

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.cordova.api.Plugin;
import org.apache.cordova.api.PluginResult;
import org.apache.cordova.api.PluginResult.Status;
import org.json.JSONArray;

import android.app.WallpaperManager;
import android.content.Context;

public class testPlugin extends Plugin {
    public final String ACTION_SET_WALLPAPER = "setWallPaper";
    @Override
    public PluginResult execute(String action, JSONArray arg1, String callbackId) {
        PluginResult result = new PluginResult(Status.INVALID_ACTION);
        if (action.equals(ACTION_SET_WALLPAPER)) {
            WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance((Context) this.ctx);
            try {
                wallpaperManager.setResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                result = new PluginResult(Status.OK);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                result = new PluginResult(Status.ERROR, e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

this is javascript file test.js

```
var TestPlugin = function () {};

TestPlugin.prototype.set = function (ms, successCallback, failureCallback) {  
//  navigator.notification.alert("OMG");
    return cordova.exec(successCallback, failureCallback, 'testPlugin', "setWallPaper", [ms]);
};

PhoneGap.addConstructor(function() {
    PhoneGap.addPlugin("test", new TestPlugin());
})
```

and main file call Plugin

```
window.plugins.test.set("kaka",
        function () { 
            navigator.notification.alert("Set Success");    
        },
        function (e) {
            navigator.notification.alert("Set Fail: " + e);
        }
    );

;
```

with android device permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER" />
```

and plugin.xml

```
 <plugin name="testPlugin" value="com.android.test.testPlugin"/>
```

while you download image with downloader plugin and save with bitmap. you just call

```
wallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap)
```

Comment: This does no longer work with phonegap 2.0 since this.ctx returns LegacyContext instead of Context. Does anyone know how it's supposed to be now? I haven't found proper documentation yet.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I fixed testPlugin.java. Changes are in bold below.

```
package com.wizeideas.ImageEvolverApp;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import org.apache.cordova.api.CallbackContext;
import org.apache.cordova.api.CordovaPlugin;
import org.apache.cordova.api.PluginResult;
import org.apache.cordova.api.PluginResult.Status;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;

import android.app.WallpaperManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.util.Log;

public class testPlugin extends CordovaPlugin {
    public final String ACTION_SET_WALLPAPER = "setWallPaper";
    @Override
    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray arg1, CallbackContext callbackContext) {
        PluginResult result = new PluginResult(Status.INVALID_ACTION);
        if (action.equals(ACTION_SET_WALLPAPER)) {
            Context ctx = this.cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext();
            WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(ctx);
            try {
                InputStream bitmap=null;
                try {
                    bitmap=this.cordova.getActivity().getAssets().open("www/img/" + arg1.getString(0));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } //reference to image folder

                Bitmap bit=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bitmap);
                wallpaperManager.setBitmap(bit);
                result = new PluginResult(Status.OK);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                result = new PluginResult(Status.ERROR, e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        callbackContext.sendPluginResult(result);
        return true;
    }
}
```

You also need to change config.xml file under res/xml to include:

```
<feature name="testPlugin">
  <param name="android-package" value="com.companyname.yourappname.testPlugin"/>
</feature>
```