# Can I create a live wallpaper for Android with Phonegap?

Tags: android, cordova, wallpaper

We have a WebGL-JavaScript app that renders beautiful animated effects. We hope to create a live wallpaper for Android from it using Phonegap.

Is it possible to create a live wallpaper for Android with JS and Phonegap now, or should we go native way?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10025625/how-to-set-image-as-wallpaper-using-android-phonegap

Comment: Amit, thank you. The link explains how to set an image as wallpaper on Android using Phonegap. But what I need is to create a WebGL app using Java Script and set it as animated wallpaper in Android.

Comment: if you want to try this you must create plugin for that because this kind of plugin not available now.

Comment: I'm new in native Android development. After 20 min Googling it seems that so far no one has made such a plugin. However, many people ask for live wallpaper and widgets support. Seems to be a not trivial task.