# Set device background using Cordova

Tags: android, ios, node.js, apache-cordova

I'm trying to set the **device's** background image in apache cordova... Is there a way to do this ? (Maybe by using the platform's API?) I am targeting  Android and ios!

Comment: This isn't possible on iOS http://stackoverflow.com/a/23272366/943544
On Android this answer looks reasonable http://stackoverflow.com/a/10038556/943544

Comment: Hm... Even if I add the dialog which pops up if you change it over the official apple photo app ?

Comment: I suspect Apple will be using their own private API for that and as the answer in the linked question notes
"Apps that use non-public APIs will be rejected"